# mips error immediate value (2147483647) out of range (0 .. 65535)

Tags: assembly, mips

Hi so this line of code is particularly giving me a hard time. `andi $13,$12,0x800`. The rest of the program seems to work fine. Where I shift using `sll $12,$12,1` to get the rest of the bit. But for some reason I am miscounting the number of 0's in the integer value. Oh yea the purpose of the program is to count the number of leading 0's in an integer number then print out the number of 0's.

```
andi $13, $12, 0x8000     
bne  $13, $0, endp         
addi $10, $10, 1
sll  $12, $12, 1           
b    pos
```

any ideas about why 0x8000 is only counting it 5 times. Better yet I don't fully understand how the immediate works. Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: _"any ideas about why 0x8000 is only counting it 5 times"_ We don't know what your input is, so impossible for us to say. Please post a _complete, minimal_ example along with expected and actual results.

Comment: i tried to use an immediate value of 0x80000000 and I got an out of bounds error which is in the title but I found when I changed it I didn't get the error but the count was wrong